# Finding value of $a$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, quadratics

Find $a$ for $f(x)= 6x^3-5x^2+5x-a.$ given that $3x^2-x+2$ is a factor of $f(x)$.

$3x^2-x+2$ posses no real roots hence I am unable to proceed.

Comment: Try long division.

Comment: How exactly to do that with an unknown

Comment: all the coefficients of $(bX+c)(3X^2-X+2)$ should be the same than those of $f$

Answer (score 3):

By long division we get,

$$6x^3-5x^2+5x-a=(3x^2-x+2)(2x-1)+(2-a)$$

But,remainder is $0$.

So,$2-a=0\implies a=2$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
f(x)&=6x^3−5x^2+5x−a\\
&=2x(3x^2-x+2)-(3x^2-x+a)
\end{align}
Obviously $a=2$.

Comment: @tatan Why is that not divisible?

Comment: Sorry...had a miscalculation....

Answer (score 1):

So you have $f(x) = 6x^3 -5x^2 + 5x - a=  (3x^2-x+2)g(x)$, with $g$ a polynom with degree $1$, ie: $g(x) = cx+d$.

Expanding the RHS, you can identify with the LHS in order to find the parameters $c,d$ and then you will be able to find $a$.